# Centering inside a <div> element

Tags: html, css, center

I know this question has been asked a million times and I've already used all those solutions in other websites I created and they worked just fine.

However, in my latest situation, the usual answers are not working for me.

This is the class that needs to have other elements centered inside it (ie. lists, tables):

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #282828;
    box-shadow: inset -6px -6px 6px -2px #1d1d1d;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

I added the `position: relative` because I put another child `<div>` inside `.container` which had its position set to `absolute`. I actually managed to center things, but that's not the kind of center I need. When I added a table-like div structure inside `.container` it went straight back to the left - no idea why.

I would appreciate some help.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/J3jm7/3/

Comment: We need to see the full HTML / CSS. JSfiddle please?

Comment: Did you try `text-align: center` on the parent?

Comment: Added the JSFiddle. Thanks for your responses. @Chad: No, I did not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center a div in a div - horizontally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Centering an inline element

To center an inline element just use `text-align:center` on the container.

```
.container {
    text-align:center
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zNuLp/)

### Centering a block-level element

Use `margin:auto` to center a block-level element such as a table within its container.

```
.container table {
    margin:auto;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u8b4B/1/)

#### Centering a list

Lists are a bit of a special case because of `li { display: list-item; }`. To center a `<ul>` you will need to change it to an `inline-block` element and center it on the container.

```
.container {
    text-align:center
}

.container ul {
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LGRqF/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the left and right margins of the element inside of your container.  Here's an example, slightly modifying your code so you can see the centering happening on the table element:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 800px;
            background-color: #282828;
            box-shadow: inset -6px -6px 6px -2px #1d1d1d;
            color: #FFF;
            border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
            float: left;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
            .container table {
                width:25%;
                height: 25%;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                border:5px solid blue;
            }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table></table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```